# Binding a Color to a DependencyProperty in UserControl

Tags: wpf, colors

I have a `UserControl` that has a `Grid` with a `Background` property that is bound. All of my other bindings work as expected, but for some reason, the only color I get in my `UserControl` is the default value I set for the `DependencyProperty`.

Referencing the `UserControl` in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<controls:MyUserControl Title="{Binding Path=MyObjects[0].Title" MyControlColor="{Binding Path=MyObjects[0].Color}" />
```

`Title` shows up as expected but the color is unchanged.

`MyUserControl` code (I use `MyControlColorBrush` for the color source, which just converts `MyControlColor` to a `SolidColorBrush`. Code on down.):

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Path=MyControlColorBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</Grid>
```

`MyUserControl.xaml.cs` code:

```
public Color MyControlColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(MyControlColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyControlColorProperty, value); }
}
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyControlColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyControlColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Black));
```

And then a property that just converts the color to a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
public SolidColorBrush MyControlColorBrush
{
    get { return new SolidColorBrush(MyControlColor); }
}
```

Any ideas on what I could be missing? If I check the value of `MyControlColor`, it's showing the right color, but the background of the `Grid` just isn't changing from `Black`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding to MyControlColorBrush only happens once when your page is first loaded. Your binding to `MyObjects[0].Color` is causing your dependency property to update but there's nothing indicating to the rest of your app that MyControlColorBrush needs to be updated as well.

There are a few ways to achieve this, the easiest is probably to just create a read-only dependency property for your brush that you update whenever you detect a change in your color property (this is similar to how the Width/ActualWidth properties work). Your control will need a DP for the color:

```
public Color MyControlColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(MyControlColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyControlColorProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyControlColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyControlColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Black, OnColorChanged));
```

And then a read-only DP for the brush:

```
public Brush MyControlColorBrush
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(MyControlColorBrushProperty); }
    protected set { SetValue(MyControlColorBrushPropertyKey, value); }
}

private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey MyControlColorBrushPropertyKey
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("MyControlColorBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUserControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyControlColorBrushProperty = MyControlColorBrushPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
```

And you'll update the brush whenever your color DP changes:

```
private static void OnColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as MyUserControl).MyControlColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)e.NewValue);
}
```

GUI elements in your custom control then bind to the read-only DP, e.g.:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Path=MyControlColorBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using parts of this and it works great.

I got rid of my regular ColorBrush property and created a dependency property with it, then I created the ColorPropertyChanged method, and I assigned the colors like this...

    (source as MyUserControl).MyControlColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush((source as MyUserControl).MyControlColor);